# I have a list of items that the user can check off, how do I keep track of which items are checked?

Tags: android, checkbox

So I have a list of goods read in from a database and the user can then select which ones (by checking them) they want to be sent to them. However I am stuck on trying to figure the best way of keeping track which items were checked off. I do not plan on having the checked marks indicated in the database so the database is out of the question. Should I just use an array at the end when they say send, that searches the array and finds which ones are checked? As of right now each row in the listview has a name, a price, and a checkbox I just through onto the  screen which is not linked up to anything. Whats the best way of doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah an array or list would work great.  If you want you can use a dictionary to store a unique key, boolean combination.

Comment: Alright, now how would I know which ones were checked? is there boolean value that I can test for on each item in the list?